# List comprehension issue

Tags: python

I am trying to create a word_list that checks if the letter is in the word_letters and replaces the dash with the correct letter. I am trying to repilcate the game of hangman

```
def hangman():
    word = get_vaild_word(words)
    word_letters = set(word.upper()) #letter in the word word_letters = set(word)
    alphabet = set(string.ascii_uppercase)
    used_letters = set() #what the user has guessed 
    print(word)
    print(word_letters)

    lives = 6

    #getting user input
    while len(word_letters) > 0 and lives > 0:
        #letters used
        print("You have", lives,"lives left and you have used these letters: ", " ".join(used_letters))

        #what the current word is (ie W - R D)
        word_list = [used_letters if letter in word else '-' for letter in word_letters]
        #I belive there is something worng with this line of code ^^^
        print("Current Word: ", " ".join(word_list))
```

What happens with this line of code is that. The code reconzies the letter and takes away a dash but fails to add the correct letter to the spot.

Comment: it looks like you switched `word` and `word_letters` in the list comprehension

Comment: `used_letters` is a `set`. The argument to `join()` has to be a list of strings.

Comment: Where do you get the user input?

Comment: You should be looping over the letters in the secret word. You need another variable holding the correct letters that the user has guessed. Then the list comprehension should be `[letter if letter in correct_guesses else '-' for letter in word]`

Comment: Don't loop over the `set`, because the letters will be out of order and duplicates will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
[used_letters if letter in word else '-' for letter in word_letters]
```

I think you may have just swapped a few variables. Currently, this reads: "For each letter in the set of distinct word letters, if that letter is in `word`, give me the *whole* set of used letters, else give me a dash". Your result will look something like

```
[{'a', 'b', 'c'}, '-', {'a', 'b', 'c'}, '-', '-']
```

It sounds like what you want is: "For each letter in the *word*, if that letter is in `used_letters`, return it, else return `'-'`, so consider

```
[letter if letter in used_letters else '-' for letter in word]
```

And honestly, to me this still reads backward. Python will understand it, but it reads completely right-to-left. The list comprehension is backward and so is the `if`, which makes a bad combination. I'd forgo the list comprehension entirely and make a helper function.

```
def masked_word(word, used_letters):
    result = []
    for letter in word:
        if letter in used_letters:
            result.append(letter)
        else:
            result.append('-')
    return result
```

and call *that* function instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the line of code to the following:

```
word_list = ['' if letter in used_letters else letter for letter in word_letters]
```

This code will first create an empty string for each letter in the `word_letters` variable. Then, it will check if the letter is in the `used_letters` variable. If it is, the code will set the string to an empty string. Otherwise, the code will set the string to the letter itself.

Comment: I think the logic of your ternary expression is backwards. You want to show the letter if it *is* in the `used_letters` set, and show a `-` if it hasn't been guessed yet.